# 'devise' is not recognised as internal or external command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems

Can anyone help me with this error, i cant use the devise gem even though it is installed, ive tried multiple versions but it still wont work?

```
Using devise 3.0.4
Using hike 1.2.3
Using multi_json 1.10.1
Using jbuilder 2.2.5
Using jquery-rails 3.1.2
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using sprockets 2.12.3
Using sprockets-rails 2.2.1
Using rails 4.1.8
Using rdoc 4.1.2
Using sass 3.2.19
Using sass-rails 4.0.5
Using sdoc 0.4.1
Using sqlite3 1.3.10
Using turbolinks 2.5.2
Using tzinfo-data 1.2014.10
Using uglifier 2.5.3
Your bundle is updated!

C:\ruby\dev\devise-test>devise -h
'devise' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\ruby\dev\devise-test>rails -v
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Rails 4.1.8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all gems have an associated executable. Devise is an authentication solution that works on top of Rails/Warden - you should be configuring it within your rails app (after adding the gem to your Gemfile).

Comment: I have used "devise g Users" to generate users before why am i not able to use it now, i even tried a fresh application to test it and still i cant use it?

Comment: It's now part of the rails generators. `rails generate devise Users` should do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Look here - https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#getting-started

You generate the devise files by running a rails generator (it mainly does configuration, changes routes.rb and if I'm remember correctly, also adds some views files). After that, it's like any other gem in your project.